# math of Diffusion ; diffusion through membrane

Tags: trigonometric-series

A liquid diffuses through a porous membrane of thickness L. If the concentration c(x,t) is maintained at c1 on the x=0 side of the membrane and c2 on the x=L side of the membrane, determine c(x,t) on the membrane. Assume that there is no liquid in the membrane initially and the Dliquid = D. Simplify the solution when the diffusion length is larger than 'L'.

Attempted this problem with trigonometric series solution but couldn't derive the equation.

Comment: Please try and give us more info on what you have tried: Calculations, the differential equation you are trying to solve with you trigonometric series etc.

Comment: I was reading this concept in a book about Diffusion by Crank and I even know the final solution to it its I don't know how to get there. In the book they have just given the final expression. I would have loved to show what I have done but my Mathjax is not great.